# Can not load data as external data from http get request when using amCharts

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

i'm working on a project and i found some issues that i don't know how to fix.
In fact, i'm using amMap and i want to load an external data coming from my API. I've a service class who get the url API  and make the http get request. When i `console.log()` the result of the request i can see my data. But when i try to link the data by doing `"polygonSeries.data = myResult"` it doesn't show anything. To test it i try to display a tooltip on hovering the map.

Please could somebody help me?

NB: my english level is not high enough so, please don't pay attention on errors...
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you should move `polygonSeries` operations in subscription

Comment: Thank for your answer, can you be more specific?

Comment: Like this https://pastebin.com/9RykP8dZ

Comment: When you set `polyginSeries.data = this.countriesList` it's undefined or set with initial value. Then `getCovidGlobalsDataCountries` resolves and set data to `this.countriesList`, but `polyginSeries.data` already initialized

Comment: Ah ok, i will try to replace this.countriesList by  polygonSeries.data in the subscribe. I will let you know if it resolve the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//The service

```
  getCovidGloblasDataCountries(): Observable<Country[]>{
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.ApiEndPointCy);
  }
```

//The typescript class

```
 countriesList: Country[];
 constructor( private covidService: CovidService) { }

// Setting the world map

setChart(): void{
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

//Initialising the data
this.covidService.getCovidGloblasDataCountries().subscribe(data => {
  this.countriesList = data;
  console.log(this.countriesList);

});

// Add expectancy data
polygonSeries.data = this.countriesList;

// Configure series
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = `
                              <div> <img src="{cyFlag}" alt="flag"> </div>
                              <div> <Strong>Pays : </Strong> {cyName} </div>
                              <div> <Strong>Cases : </Strong> {cyCases} </div>
                              <div> <Strong>Recovered : </Strong> {cyPopulation} </div>
                              <div> <Strong>Criticals : </Strong> {cyCriticals} </div>
                              <div> <Strong>Deaths : </Strong> {cyDeaths} </div>`;

polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#999");

// Create hover state and set alternative fill color
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");
```